# how to create a JSon passing urls for android?

Tags: android, json

I am a android developer.I want to create a url for my self.How to create a url for getting data and passing data trough internet.For example ( http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/)this is the url containing contacts.Like that i want to create some urls for my self.

Please any body help me and give me some tutorials for creating urls.

Answer (score 1):

To create a URL you need a live server ( for e.g. `http://111.222.111.222:8080/myJson` or http://www.myserver.com/myJson ). Then you need to deploy a file on the server which will return JSON format whenever it gets executed.

For this you need to buy a domain, web-space and live URL/IP , so it is going to cost. However there is an alternate way which is free, but the procedure is bit lengthy.

Comment: @thejh, ip can't be greater than 255 :P

Comment: Actually, it's 255 (or 0xff), but that's exactly why I'm suggesting it. :P

Answer (score 0):

You could host the server on your home computer, and forward the port to it through your router.

To do this you will either need a static IP or use a dynamic DNS system like NoIp.com.